# Variable text in SVG, PHP

Tags: php, variables, svg, text

I want to call a function to get a variable in a SVG figure.
How can i get GetCookie(user) (Returns username stored in a cookie)

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 602 580" style="enable-background:new 0 0 602 580;" xml:space="preserve">
    <text x="5" y="5" alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Verdana" font-size="30">GetCookie(user)</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Hi, i already spent half a day searching for this. But thanks for the heads up :)